# Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql, errors, spatial

The following simple test returns an error

```
CREATE TABLE track (
  position point NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO track VALUES (
  position=ST_PointFromText('POINT(-45.62390335574153 -3.9551761173743847)')
);
```

Error:

> ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the event you're asking what is happening rather than how do you fix it, check out my question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194120/2639

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong syntax...  Instead of

```
INSERT INTO track VALUES (
    position=ST_PointFromText(...)
);
```

use

```
INSERT INTO track SET
    position=ST_PointFromText(...);
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 3):

I am using Spring Boot data JPA and MySQL.

Please add below properties in spring boot application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect
```

I was successful to save Point column

```
Hibernate: select max(id) from shoplocation
Hibernate: insert into shoplocation (address, area, geo_location, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9 and Hibernate 5.2 and MySQL 5.6