# What does k=v do in the context of INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (expr)

Tags: mysql, insert

Coming off [this answer,](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/170787/2639) I'm wondering why the lexer allowed it to get all the way down to the geometry grammar in this [`INSERT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x varchar(255) );
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( x='foo' );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

I know that's not right, and [as the answer above indicates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/170787/2639) that it should be `INSERT INTO tbl SET`, but what's happening? How is MySQL interpreting that? In PostgreSQL, such a syntax is rejected.

```
test=# CREATE TABLE foo ( x varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( x='foo' );
```

PostgreSQL interprets it as a column reference and errors out, further providing a hint

```
ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( x='foo' );
HINT:  There is a column named "x" in table "foo", but it cannot be referenced
from this part of the query.
```

MySQL Seems to check to make sure the field name exists at run time but for what end I have no idea.

```
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( DOESNOTEXIST=5 );
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'DOESNOTEXIST' in 'field list'
> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( x=5 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

If it **does not** exist you get an error. I'm not sure what happens if it **does** exist though. `NULL` is inserted, but why? Why that would be any less of an error. Can someone explain?

I know MySQL has a [User-Defined Variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) syntax, however I don't think that has anything to do with it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you created the table with this command

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x varchar(255) );
```

column`x` was defined with an implicit default of `NULL`.

When you compare a non-existent variable with a real value as you did before you get `NULL`.

When it comes to the expression you gave, `x=5`, you are asking if `NULL` equals 5. In terms of symantics, `NULL` cannot by compared with anything:

```
mysql> select NULL = 5;
+----------+
| NULL = 5 |
+----------+
|     NULL |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

not even with `NULL` itself

```
mysql> select NULL = NULL;
+-------------+
| NULL = NULL |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It needs a content context (if that makes any sense).

Anyway, when you tried to evaluate `x=5`, that gets processed internally as evaluating `x`, which of course, is `NULL` with the row coming into existence, followed by making a comparison with a non-NULL value of `5`. Since the expression must evaluate as `NULL`, you essentially did this:

```
mysql> insert into foo values (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

which has the same effect as as doing this

```
mysql> insert into foo values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Interesting! **Really good answer Rolando.** I didn't even think about that. So the column name in the context of `INSERT ... VALUES` is the default value in MySQL, just like `DEFAULT`. I wonder if people actually use that and if it's supported/documented.

Comment: In the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), inserting with `INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES();` is mentioned. It is allowed except for what the doc says : `If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL uses the implicit default value for any column that has no explicitly defined default. If strict mode is enabled, an error occurs if any column has no default value.`

Comment: So I enabled strict mode, It still didn't error. Is that referring to this functionality? It's not clear to me.

Comment: When I created your table on my laptop I ran `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G`. I got `Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `x` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`. So, x has the default of `NULL` hardcoded in. I don't know of any instance of creating a column that does not have a default in place. If you can create a table that literally does not have a default value of any kind, then an error should be manifested.

Comment: It looks as though MySql also allows you to reference the post insert values of other columns, http://rextester.com/AJNUQE9325

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA figured it out, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194134/2639 BTW, it's interesting that this is the one application that isn't addressed by the docs you cited. ;)

Comment: +1 to Rolando. `CREATE TABLE foo (x int default 5); INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x = 5);` inserts `1` (the TRUE value).

Comment: Even with that explanation, PostgreSQL's response seems like a much saner way to handle this case.

Comment: @Wildcard I would have to agree. It's like putting a piece of the documentation in the error message.