# Assigning empty string to INT NULL field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datatypes, type-conversion

Point me a reference what happens if empty string (`''`) is assigned to a `INT NULL` field.

Does it become `NULL` or `0`?

Do all versions (starting from 5) of MySQL do the same?

Comment: The insert statement will throw an error since you aren't supplying a valid value for an INT column.

Comment: This is a case where you could have answered your own question via a simple use case -- as Evan did.  It is a good idea to get in the habit of such.

Comment: As for "all versions" -- The answer is probably yes for at least 4.0..8.0.  However, there have been changes to the _default_ value of `sql_mode`, so the apparent action may have changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the `sql_mode` you're running as. If the mode isn't `strict` then you'll get the inserted value to be the same as the coercion to that type,

```
SELECT CAST('' AS int);
+-----------------+
| CAST('' AS int) |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

This however is insanity, as you can see..

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( id int, a int, b int NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
  (1,1,NULL),
  (2,NULL,''),
  (3,'',NULL),
  (4,NULL,NULL);

SELECT * FROM foo;
+------+------+---+
| id   | a    | b |
+------+------+---+
|    1 |    1 | 0 |
|    2 | NULL | 0 |
|    3 |    0 | 0 |
|    4 | NULL | 0 |
+------+------+---+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So we can tell MySQL to try to be less of a joke, and more like a real database, like PostgreSQL

```
SET sql_mode='strict_all_tables';
```

And then,

```
TRUNCATE foo;

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
  (1,1,NULL),
  (2,NULL,''),
  (3,'',NULL),
  (3,NULL,NULL);
```

But this time we get,

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'b' cannot be null

For more information see,

- [What is MySQL's "Implicit Default Value" and how does it work with "strict mode"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194134/2639)

Comment: Both `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` will prevent the "funny" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [previous answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212363/22336), if you migrate or use Amazon RDS it takes the default value and it can be changed only with at least one of the following values:

```
ALLOW_INVALID_DATES, ANSI, ANSI_QUOTES, DB2, 
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE, 
IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS, IGNORE_SPACE, MAXDB, MSSQL, MYSQL323, 
MYSQL40, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO, 
NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES, NO_DIR_IN_CREATE, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION, 
NO_FIELD_OPTIONS, NO_KEY_OPTIONS, NO_TABLE_OPTIONS, 
NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, 
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, ORACLE, PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH, 
PIPES_AS_CONCAT, POSTGRESQL, REAL_AS_FLOAT, 
STRICT_ALL_TABLES, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, TRADITIONAL
```

And there is no way to insert the *empty* setting

Answer (score 1):

I got around this, by forcing the value to become null with the function
`NULLIF(_variable_,'')`